# Selecting both links and anchors using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am using screaming frog and I want to do this using XPath.

**Extract all links and anchors** containing a certain class from the main body content
but I want to exclude all links within **div.list**

Right now I am trying this but it's not working too well, plus I want it to spit it out in text form in possible.

```
//div[@class="page-content"]/*[not(class="list")]//a[@data-wpel-link="internal"]
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//a[@data-wpel-link="internal"][not(ancestor::div[@class="list"])]
```

will select all `a` elements with the given attribute value that do not have an ancestor `div` of the given class.

You can, of course, prefix any heritage in which to restrict the selection, e.g:

```
//div[@class="page-content"]//a[@data-wpel-link="internal"]
                               [not(ancestor::div[@class="list"])]
```

Comment: Thanks. That says invalid xpath though. Must be a typo?

Comment: Nice, thanks. Any idea how to extract both the anchors and the urls in text format?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the expected output explicitly.